# How can I convert a CSV file, which is nested by means of columns, to a nested dictionary with Python?

Tags: python

I have a google sheet of categories.

[Google Sheets of nested Categories][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OAi5.png / And I exported this to a csv file resulting in this:

```
Substructure,,,
,Foundations,,
,,Standard Foundations,
,,,Wall Foundations   
,,,Column Foundations   
,,,Standard Foundation Supplementary Components   
,,Special Foundations,
,,,Driven Piles   
,,,Bored Piles   
,,,Caissons   
,,,Special Foundation Walls   
,,,Foundation Anchors   
,,,Underpinning   
,,,Raft Foundations   
,,,Pile Caps   
,,,Grade Beams
```

Using Python, I would like to convert this CSV file into a nested dictionary with the following format:

```
categories = [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: 'parent'
    }, {
      id: 1,
      title: 'parent',
      subs: [
        {
          id: 10,
          title: 'child'
        }, {
          id: 11,
          title: 'child'
        }, {
          id: 12,
          title: 'child'
        }
      ]
    }, {
      id: 2,
      title: 'parent'
    },
    // more data here
];
```

So, to be clear, each csv row should be added to a dictionary like this: {id:x,title:y}, and if it has children, it should look like this: {id:x,title:y,subs:[comma separated children dicts]}.

I've spent about a day and a half on this using similar questions on here, but they are all just too different for my current level of skills to make them work for this. I feel terrible and would really appreciate some help. If possible, I'd like to use the solution on other scenarios as well, with varying  levels of children. This example has three levels for children, some have only two or one.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: What exactly was the problem when you tried to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion!

```py
import csv
from pprint import pprint

filename = 'myfile.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    matrix = list(csv.reader(f))

current_id = -1


def next_id():
    global current_id
    current_id += 1
    return current_id


def group(column, rows):
    if column == len(matrix[0]) - 1:
        return [
            {'id': next_id(), 'title': row[column].strip()}
            for row in rows
        ]

    result = []
    item = None
    sub = None
    for row in rows:
        title = row[column]
        if title:
            if item:
                item['subs'] = group(column + 1, sub)
            item = {'id': next_id(), 'title': title.strip()}
            result.append(item)
            sub = []
        else:
            sub.append(row)
    item['subs'] = group(column + 1, sub)
    return result


pprint(group(0, matrix))
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 0,
  'subs': [{'id': 1,
            'subs': [{'id': 2,
                      'subs': [{'id': 3, 'title': 'Wall Foundations'},
                               {'id': 4, 'title': 'Column Foundations'},
                               {'id': 5,
                                'title': 'Standard Foundation Supplementary Components'}],
                      'title': 'Standard Foundations'},
                     {'id': 6,
                      'subs': [{'id': 7, 'title': 'Driven Piles'},
                               {'id': 8, 'title': 'Bored Piles'},
                               {'id': 9, 'title': 'Caissons'},
                               {'id': 10,
                                'title': 'Special Foundation Walls'},
                               {'id': 11, 'title': 'Foundation Anchors'},
                               {'id': 12, 'title': 'Underpinning'},
                               {'id': 13, 'title': 'Raft Foundations'},
                               {'id': 14, 'title': 'Pile Caps'},
                               {'id': 15, 'title': 'Grade Beams'}],
                      'title': 'Special Foundations'}],
            'title': 'Foundations'}],
  'title': 'Substructure'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax you were looking for is as follows:

```
with open('file.csv', mode='r') as infile:
reader = csv.reader(infile)
with open('file_new.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    mydict = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}
```

Alternately, for python <= 2.7.1, you want:

```
mydict = dict((rows[0],rows[1]) for rows in reader)
```